# gst_bus_sync_handler not sending prepare-window-handle message

Tags: c, udp, gtk, gstreamer

I've built a Gstreamer pipeline that uses xvoverlay, udpsrc and xvimagesink.

I'm running 4 parallel pipelines with different sources, i'm trying to get these to show in a GTK window. I create 4 GtkWidgets and initialize them with gtk_drawing_area_new();

I've followed [this](https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/gst-plugins-base-video-1.0/videooverlay.html?gi-language=c) guide and implemented realize_cb and the bus sync handler.

The problem is that it works, most of the time. Every now and then the bus sync handler never sends the prepare-window-handle message for 1 or 2 of the sinks. The code that sets the sync handler is clearly there, windows are initialized and everything, but i never get the message.

```
static GstBusSyncReply bus_sync_handler (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * message, gpointer ptr)
{
    uint8_t index = *((uint8_t *) ptr);

    if (!gst_is_video_overlay_prepare_window_handle_message (message))
        return GST_BUS_PASS;

    if (window_handles[index] != 0) {
        GstVideoOverlay *overlay;

        overlay = GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (message));
        gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (overlay, window_handles[index]);
    }
    gst_message_unref (message);
    (void)bus;

    return GST_BUS_DROP;
}
```

```
stream->queue_display = gst_element_factory_make("queue", NULL);
stream->videoscale = gst_element_factory_make ("videoscale", NULL);
stream->videosink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", NULL);


GstBus *bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE (stream->pipeline));
gst_bus_set_sync_handler (bus, (GstBusSyncHandler) bus_sync_handler, (gpointer) stream->window_index, NULL);
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(stream->pipeline), gst_object_ref(stream->queue_display), stream->videoscale, stream->videosink, NULL);

if (!gst_element_link_many(stream->queue_display, stream->videoscale, stream->videosink, NULL)) {
//Error handling
}
```

Pipeline is set to playing in a later stage after this.

Any ideas?

Comment: So are you sure the callback does not trigger, or is the the overlay just not working? We don't know about you code's variables types. E.g. is the array of indices really a uint8_t, or is it an int? How big is it?

Comment: I know this is a super late reply, but figured I'd reply for completion. The problem turned out to be with the source stream being bad.